# jQuery - I need to use Ajax on data gathered from Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

So this is what I'm doing.
I'm using the DataTables plugin, and also the magnific popup plugin. What I'm trying to do, is have a table of users, load dynamically from a database, and loaded into the DataTables, table. There is a link, in each row, for the specified user. Now, what I'm trying to do, is when you click the link, instead of going to another page, it create a popup with the data. It doesn't work. I debugged it sort of, and what I'm seeing, is since, the data is pulled from the database, through ajax, the popup plugin, doesn't see the data. Is there a way to get around this? I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible, and reduce CPU load on the server, so..

```
<table id="player_table" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Last IP</th>
            <th>Total Commands</th>
            <th>Total NPC Clicks</th>
            <th>Total Object Clicks</th>
            <th>Total Item Clicks</th>
            <th>Last Trade</th>
            <th>Details</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>142</td>
            <td>Dayghost</td>
            <td>127.0.0.1</td>
            <td>325</td>
            <td>568</td>
            <td>1433</td>
            <td>12503</td>
            <td>16:42</td>
            <td><a href="player.php?id=2" class="popup">more Info</a></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This table is loaded dynamically, and has 150 random whatevers in it.

The following is the ajax, that gathers the data.

```
$('#player_table').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "serverside/handler.php"
});
```

This is the popup module

```
$('.popup').magnificPopup({
    midClick: true,
    type: 'ajax'
});
```

The popup module, will only work, `IF` and only `if`, the data was loaded at the time the page was made. It won't work on the data gathered through `ajax`. I tested this on a test button.

I edited the usage of the `.popup class`

Comment: Pls provide any code that we have a start to help you.

Comment: So, we have this table. a demo table.

Comment: Please provide some code please @demitchell14

Comment: provided @HarigovindR

Answer (score 0):

Although I can't see any html elements with the class `.popup` on them in your code (?) I'm guessing what you need to do is call Magnific popup **after** your content is generated.

Order of events would be:

- Page is loaded with the static data
- Magnific is initialised on the data currently on the page
- Data is refreshed using AJAX
- Magnific no longer tied to any elements on the page, so magnific needs to be reinitialised

This would be as simple as calling:

```
$('.popup').magnificPopup({
    midClick: true,
    type: 'ajax'
});
```

After the AJAX content has loaded.

Comment: The problem with what you're idea is.. that method is called, every time the row is clicked. The popup class is an super class. I use it, in every row. BUT the data is never the same, by the way MagnificPopup plugin actually works. it uses an href to grab the data. The URL is.. [link](http://rspsanalysis.comeze.com/). If you visit, you'll see what the problem is itself

Comment: I don't understand - the solution you've used is exactly what I proposed?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

I put function..

```
$('.popup').magnificPopup({
    midClick: true,
    type: 'ajax'
});
```

into a onComplete setting in DataTables.